# Why 'BitConverter.GetBytes()' accept argument of type 'byte' and returns always a 2-bytes array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm using `BitConverter.GetBytes()` to convert various variables (of different types) to a byte array, to pass it to a custom method where I need to check the value of each byte.

I've noticed that I can pass a variable of type `byte` to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` (even if it is not listed in the Overload list: [see related MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and in this case I always have a 2-bytes array as return value.
Shouldn't I have a single-byte array as return value? How does .NET interpret the byte argument?

Sample:

```
byte arg = 0x00;
byte[] byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(arg);
// Result: byteArr is a 2-bytes array where byte[0] = 0 and byte[ 1] = 0
```

Comment: The sample would be more interesting with `arg != 0x00`

Comment: Like the answers are stating, you're seeing the results of an implicit conversion of `byte` to `short`. Here's the list of predefined implicit numeric conversions in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The framework designers assumed that you didn't need help converting a byte to a byte.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I didn't know of the existence of this table, very interesting. (And thanks all for the support!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you look up [GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) you will find that there is no overload that takes a `byte` parameter.

You are looking at the results of the closest match, `GetBytes(Int16)` and that of course produces a `byte[2]`.

In other words, your code:

```
byte arg = 0x00;
byte[] byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(arg);
```

is equivalent to:

```
byte arg = 0x00;
short _temp = arg;
byte[] byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(_temp);
```

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers have pointed out, there is no GetBytes overload that takes a byte parameter. The next question is why does it choose the overload that takes a short. It could pick any of these for example:

```
GetBytes(short)
GetBytes(int)
GetBytes(long)
GetBytes(float)
...
```

The reasoning for why it chooses short is not just because short is the next closest thing. There is better reasoning behind it. The C# language specification explains:

"Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from a type S to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from a type S to a type T2, the better conversion of the two conversions is determined as follows" [1]

Here are two possible conversions from S to either T1 or T2:

```
      S         
C1   byte     short (T1)
C2   byte     int   (T2)
```

The rule that works here is:

"If an implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, C1 is the better conversion."

There's is an implicit conversion from short to int, but not from int to short, so the conversion from byte to short is chosen.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339(v=vs.71).aspx  (old copy)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually using the overload for `short` instead of `byte`, which means it's up-casting your byte to a `short`, which is 2 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload for `GetBytes` which accepts a `byte`.

However, Section 6.1.2 of the C# language spec says that there is an implicit numeric conversion

> • From byte to short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.

This causes the compiler to convert the `byte` to `short` (which is 2 bytes), which causes the method to return a 2 byte array.